# Ruby on rails polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, polymorphic-associations

Is there a difference between the has_many , has_and_belongs_to_many and the polymorphic association.
Why should I use polymorphic association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_many`, `has_and_belongs_to_many` and the *polymorphic* associations are solutions to different problems.

- `has_many` means you have a parent object that has many other children. While the children do only belong to that specific parent.
- `has_and_belongs_to_many` means the objects are not structured in a hierarchical structure. And that the objects on both sides can be connected to mutiple others. A good example is probably a tagging system. A thing can be tagged with multiple tags. But the tags do not only belong to one thing, they can be added to other things too.
- `polymorphic associations` are used when the association doesn't point to one specific other model. An example might be an `Author` model that has a `created_work` association, but it doesn't point to a decicated `CreatedWork` model. But instead, it can return different things, like an instance of a `Book`, a `Play` an `Article`, or a simple `Comment` which are all different classes and have different database tables.